# SimpleCursorAdapter error

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

When I use a constructor of SimpleCursorAdapter it tells me that constructor is undefined.

What should I do?

```
public class ReminderListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] from = new String[] {ReminderProvider.COLUMN_TITLE};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1};
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.reminder_row, null, from, 2, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the line to this one:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    R.layout.reminder_row, null, from, to, 0);
```

You had a "2" instead of "to"

SimpleCursorAdapter's constructor:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, 
                                String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Comment: Sorry, it was a sill mistake *__________________*


Thanks u Benoit for informing me

it took me hours me and my partner to find the reason *___*

Comment: sometimes you need need to go to bed ;) Good luck for the rest